# How to solve $\sum_{Q \in S} \operatorname{Tr}(QA)^n $ where S is a set of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve $$\sum_{Q \in S} (\operatorname{Tr}(QA))^n $$ where S is a set of permutation matrices and $A$ is an arbitrary matrix.

I can solve for $n=1$, in which case the solution is

$$=(d-1)! \mathbf{1}^T A \mathbf{1} $$ where $d$ is the dimension of $Q$.

I am skeptical there is an analytic form for n>1, but I am asking here just in case there is an approximate/exact form. Any ideas?

Comment: Just for clarification, is it $\operatorname{Tr}((QA)^n)$ or $(\operatorname{Tr}(QA))^n$?

Comment: Also I suspect that, when $n=1$, the answer is $(d-1)! \mathbf{1}^{T}A\mathbf{1}$. (As a sanity check, test this with the matrix $A$ whose entries are all 1's.)

Comment: @SangchulLee I meant $(Tr(QA))^n$, and yes, you are right, it should be $d-1$ instead of $d$. Thanks for checking! (edited the post)

Comment: For $n=2$ we have
$$ \sum_{Q\in S}(\operatorname{Tr}(QA))^2
= (d-2)!\Biggl[ \biggl( \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} \biggr)^2 - \sum_{i,j_1,j_2}a_{i,j_1}a_{i,j_2} - \sum_{i_1,i_2,j}a_{i_1,j}a_{i_2,j} + d \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}^2 \Biggr]. $$ My guess is that, if $n\ll d$, then $$\sum_{Q\in S}(\operatorname{Tr}(QA))^n\approx (d-n)!(\mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}A\mathbf{1})^n. $$